# Obtener el resultado de un setTimeOut dentro de una promesa NODEJS

Tags: nodejs, promesas, asincronismo

Hola estoy llamando a una funcion, la cual tiene dentro un setTimeOut que espera 10 segundos y me regresa un string, pero no encuentro como esperar ese tiempo y luego continuar con la ejecucion, ya que adicional, ese string lo tengo que devolver

```
const promise = new Promise( async (resolve, reject) => {
    // Espera un string que convertire a JSON
    const timbrar = await timbrarEnMercurio(serieFolioBuscar);

    if ( timbrar != '') {
        resolve(timbrar)
    } else {
        reject("Error")
    }
  })

  promise.then(res => {
    return res;
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log("ERROR");
      console.log(err)
  })
```

Este es el metodo al que le paso el string, y tiene el setTimeOut que espera los 10 segundos, y al final pongo el return de un string

```
export const timbrarEnMercurio = async (serieFolioBuscar: string): Promise<string> => {

fs.writeFile(archivo, contenido, (err: any) => {
        if(err) throw('Hubo un error al escribir en el archivo');
        
        let promiseWithSetTimout = new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {

          setTimeout (() => {
            if(fs.existsSync(archivoSalida)) {  
              const fs = require('fs');
  
              fs.readFile(archivoSalida, 'utf8', (err: any, data: any) => {                
                let respuesta = `{"mensaje": "Factura timbrada"}`;
                respuestaFinal = respuesta;
              });
              resolve("Factura timbrada");
            } else {    
              // OTRO JSON
              respuestaFinal = respuesta;
            }          
          }, 15000)
        });

        promiseWithSetTimout.then (response => {
          console.log ('La promiseWithSetTimout funciona:', response)
        }).catch (error => {
            console.log ('La promiseWithTimeout no funciona:')
        })
        
      });

  return respuestaFinal;
}
```

Comment: Segun yo, dentro del promiseWithSetTimeOut.then, deberia hacer el return respuestaFinal;, pero me marca error en la funcion de que estoy regresando VOID, por eso lo puse al final

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que puedo entender, es que necesitas el valor de la variable "respuesta", el cual lo tienes que obtener del Promise que tienes en tu código. En tu código, veo que usas el resolve solamente en el if, si en caso entra al else, no usas el resolve, por ende no va devolver nada tu promise. Puedes modificar tu código de timbrarEnMercurio de esta forma:

```
export const timbrarEnMercurio = async (serieFolioBuscar: string): 
  Promise<string> => {
      fs.writeFile(archivo, contenido, (err: any) => {
         if(err) throw('Hubo un error al escribir en el archivo');
      })
      return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => setTimeout (() => {
          if(fs.existsSync(archivoSalida)) {  
            const fs = require('fs');

            fs.readFile(archivoSalida, 'utf8', (err: any, data: any) => {                
              let respuesta = `{"mensaje": "Factura timbrada","error":false}`;
              resolve(respuesta);
            });
          } else {
            let respuesta = `{"mensaje":"Error al timbrar","error":true}`;
              resolve(respuesta);
          }
               
        }, 15000)
      );
    
  }
```

Comment: Añadi al string el campo error, y donde lo mando a llamar lo convierto a JSON, no use reject, ya que siempre voy a devolver un string